# How do I create a dashboard link in my Rails user controller?

Tags: ruby, controller, routes, config, ruby-on-rails-5

I’m using Rails 5.  When my user is logged in, I want to replace the ‘/users/4’ action with a generic ‘/dashboard’ home link.  I would also like the remove the user’s ability to typing in ‘/users/##’ into the browser, instead only allowing them to visit ‘/dashboard’.  How do I do this?  Currently, in my config/routes.rb I have

```
  get '/dashboard', to: 'users#show'
  resources :users
```

and in my users_controller.rb file I have

```
  def show
    @user = User.find(params[:id])
    @user_subscriptions = UserSubscription.find_active_subscriptions_by_user(@user)
  end
```

But currently when I visit “/dashboard” in my browser, I get the error

*Couldn't find User with 'id'=*

How can I set up my route to disable the show action but allow /dashboard to successfully navigate to the action above?

Comment: Are you using devise?

Comment: Nooooooooooooooo (need extra chars or SO won't take comment)

Comment: If you want a good suggestion, use devise for your atuthentication. It will provide you methods to make what you need in a much easier way. Besides, it will provide you with the structure needed to authenticate with Facebook, Twitter, Googe+ and and other OAuth provider.

Comment: In this case of yours, one single if would solve all this problem and you'd have `current_user` to avoid this `Could't find User with 'id'=` error you are getting...

Comment: I'm somewhat new to Rails and maybe that's why I'm not understanding what you're describing.  How does an "if" help rewrite my brokne "get '/dashboard', to: 'users#show'" rule and disable the "show" action?

Comment: @Natalia how are you saving your user (whom ever is logged in)?

Comment: I'm not saying this. What I am saying is: You may have a great tool for authentication in [Devise gem](https://github.com/plataformatec/devise), which would make this task easier. If you are going to user Rails, I suggest you to take some time to study Devise.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What I like to do is something like this

```
  get '/dashboard' => 'users#show', as: :dashboard
```

now on your view you can do

`link_to 'Dashboard', dashboard_path(current_user)`

and in the controller you can do

```
  def show
    params[:id] == current_user.id unless params[:id]
    @user = User.find(params[:id])
    @user_subscriptions = UserSubscription.find_active_subscriptions_by_user(@user)
  end
```

Comment: But this `current_user` you are picking from devise gem, isn't it? The OP is not using devise. I suggested it in my comments.

Comment: That is true, I have to find out what they are using  and set `current_user` to what ever they are using `session[:user]`

Comment: Why are you finding user again? It is already in `current_user`.

Comment: You might want to see another's user dashboard

Comment: NO, I definitely don't want users looking at each other's dashboards, so I assume the first line in show would just become "params[:id] = current_user.id unless params[:id]".